# How to calculate means when you have missing values?

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to calculate the mean of the data frame that has some missing values. The sum of the data frame is 500 and the number of cells is 28. therefore the mean should be 17.8571. However, when calculating in R I need to mark the missing cells with 0 that changes the mean value

[image]

[image]

Sample data:

```
    df<-structure(list(`10` = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10), `20` = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `30` = c(30, 30, 30, 30, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `40` = c(40, 40, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Sample code:

Where is my mistake?

```
df1<-rowMeans(df, na.rm=TRUE) # I also tried colMeans

df2<-mean(df1)
```

Comment: How do you get `17.8571` as mean?

Comment: @Ronak thanks basically i selected in excel the table and it shows me the average is 17.8571

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match `mean` with excel you can repeat the `time` value `df` number of times.

```
mean(rep(df$time, df$df))
#[1] 17.85714
```

Answer (score 3):

```r
sum(df,na.rm = TRUE)/sum(!is.na(df))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your `data.frame` to a vector using `unlist` and calculate then the `mean` with the argument `na.rm=TRUE` to skip `NA`.

```
mean(unlist(df), na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 17.85714
```

Another option is to convert the `data.frame` to a matrix.

```
mean(as.matrix(df), na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 17.85714
```